# Facebook comment shows to much white space after JQuery shows it in Chrome

Tags: jquery, facebook

I have a Facebook comment box, just using the html5 method provided by the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) provided by Facebook themselves. Initially its hidden with a CSS class called .hide which is nothing more than display: none. Whenever I press the desired reactions button it removes the class hide from the div the comments are in and the comments are shown. Only Chrome gives me a hard time because it adds allot of extra white space underneath the comments.

I've tried fixing this by checking the browser with JQuery and use a negative margin-top value if it was Chrome so the problem would not show. However if multiple comments are added this negative value isn't enough because the white space gets bigger with every comment being made. If i dont use JQuery to hide the div, i have no extra white space. How can I get ride of this extra unnecessary white space?

Website which shows the problem:

http://www.trailercloud.nl/index.php

Press the 'Reacties' text button to toggle the facebook comments div. It sometimes wont show the white space but after a refresh it does!

Comment: Try the xfbml code, instead of html5 code.

Comment: Think i tried that before but also this does not fix the problem. The weird thing is that on the first change of code it works fine, but after a reload it shows the same old problem. Could have something to do with chrome cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
$('.combut').on('click', function(){
    $('#vid_comments').toggleClass();
    if($('#vid_comments').is(':visible')){
        $('.fb_ltr').css({height:''});
    }
});
```

P.S. I was testing this code your page using console. I found out that you need to add height for .typeshare class too. Make the height of typeshare class as 70px and it works fine.

Comment: Sounded like a solid idea but it just keeps showing the same whitespace.. Without it being hidden it shows just fine. I tried using the fb version of document.ready to make sure it loaded completely but still no succes

Comment: Seems like you edited your previous answer? Anyways i tried this too but still no succes. It probably worked for you the first time because after editing code it does work. But if you reload one time it shows this giant whitespace again.

Comment: Edited my answer again. I tried in console and it worked. Can you try the above code?

Comment: Seems like that did the job! Been struggeling with this problem for a couple of weeks, thanks allot!

Comment: It did create another problem though it seems, when closing the div and reopening it, it only shows the upper part of the form. It no longer shows the rest of the form. You might have a fix for this aswell?

Comment: remove the .not(':visible') part

Comment: That was for testing, purposes my bad. But that does not fix the newly created problem!

Answer (score 0):

The extra white space you are talking about is created because of the explicit height which is set to the embedded iframe. It has an height of 882px in my browser (Chrome on Mac OS X 10.7). Maybe you can remove this height in some sort of way (e.g. using javascript)?

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fb-comments iframe').css({height: '282px', overflow: 'auto'});
});
```

Does that do the trick (maybe play around with the pixel height and add an if statement for Chrome browsers)?

Comment: Yes i noticed the iFrame was to big so i used jQuery to check if the browser was chrome so i would give it a negative value. However for every comment there is more whitespace, so it depends on the ammount of comments and i dont see how i can fix that.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. After the first reload it went fine but after reloading the page again it still shows all the white space.

Comment: Can you remove the code and make it as it was in the beginning. I'll try again.

Comment: I changed the footer code on the subpage: http://www.trailercloud.nl/gctv/ which is exactly the same as home but just shows different video's